# how to fetch records set from series of records in a RDD based on criteria?

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I am new to Spark and I am struggling to resolve following problem with spark. I have a table which contains large number of records.Table contains student_id, course_id, risk_date, first_name, last_name. According to the business scenario there can be multiple risk_dates for one student_id and course_id. So I need to get the student_id, course_id,  risk_date for for particular student_id and course_id with latest risk_date.

If I mention my scanario in SQL query it would be like

```
select student_id, course_id, max(risk_date) from
students group by  student_id, course_id
```

My Scala code would be like below.

```
val sqlCaller = sparkSession.read.format("jdbc")
  .option("driver", "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver")
  .option("url", url)
  .option("dbtable", "student_risk")
  .option("user", "dmin")
  .option("password", "admin123")
  .load()
sqlCaller.cache();

val studentRDD = sqlCaller.rdd.map(r => (r.getString(r.fieldIndex("course_id")), r.getString(r.fieldIndex("student_id")), r.getTimestamp(r.fieldIndex("risk_date"))))
```

Can I do this using a filter? I dont't want to use SQL statement for fetching the data match with my requirement. Can anybody please help me to do this?

Answer (score 0):

You can try this (updated):

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession

val spark = SparkSession
  .builder()
  .getOrCreate()

import spark.implicits._

val df = Seq(
  (1, 1, "2017-01-01"),
  (1, 1, "2017-01-02"),
  (1, 2, "2017-01-04"),
  (1, 2, "2017-01-05"),
  (2, 1, "2017-01-01")
).toDF("student_id", "course_id", "risk_date")

df.groupBy($"student_id", $"course_id").agg(max("risk_date")).show
```

Comment: @Anushka i've updated the answer. please, check ones more